# Get parent element id using javascript (Chrome OS)

Tags: javascript, html

Ok I'm going to be extremely specific this time.

```
curAcc = 0;
newItemInfo = null;
newItemId = null;
removeButtonId = null;

function addAccount(method, account) {
  curAcc = curAcc + 1;
  if (method == "new") {
    newItemId = "a" + curAcc;
    removeButtonId = "ra" + curAcc + "btn";

    newItemInfo = {
      Website: websiteIn.value,
      Username: usernameIn.value,
      Password: passwordIn.value,
      Id: newItemId,
      RemoveButton: {Id: removeButtonId}
    };
  } else if (method == "load") {}
  console.log(newItemInfo);

  newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.innerHTML =
    "<li><label><b>Website:</b></label> <input type='text' value='" + 
      newItemInfo.Website + "' id='a" + curAcc + "ws'></li>" +
    "<li><label><b>Username:</b></label> <input type='text' value='" + 
      newItemInfo.Username + "' id='a" + curAcc + "un'></li>" +
    "<li><label><b>Password:</b></label> <input type='text' value='" + 
      newItemInfo.Password + "' id='a" + curAcc + "pw'></li>" +
    "<li><button id='" + newItemInfo.RemoveButton.Id + "'>Remove</button>
      </li>" +
    "<br/><br/>";
   newItem.setAttribute("id", newItemId);
   accountList.appendChild(newItem);

   removeButton = document.getElementById(removeButtonId);
   removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   console.log("Button ID:" + this.id);
 });
```

}

The remove button along with the list items are created using .innerHTML.
I tried using accountList.removeChild(document.getElementById(newItemId));
It worked but it only got rid of the most recently created list item and doesn't get rid of anything else after the first use. Can anyone tell me how to get the remove button to remove newItem from the list using addEventListener?

Comment: If the question has been answered satisfactory can you please mark it as "answered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is losing scope once you create an element in a function and the function ends.

You can pass on this scope by binding it to the even listenet. Pass the `this` identifier by binding it to the function with `.bind(this)`. Then you can call the element by using the `target` selector.

By using the `event.target` selector you have the button. The parent of that (`parentNode`) is the listitem itself. The parent of that is the actual list. I'm guessing you want to remove the li item from the list. And not just the button from the li item.

I wrote the code a bit more expansive to make it more obvious.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list"); // The list element

addButton = document.getElementById("btnAdd"); // The add button
addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newButton = document.createElement("button"); // Create a new button
  var btnText = document.createTextNode("Remove"); // Create the button's text
  newButton.appendChild(btnText); // Add the text to the button
  
  newButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) { // Create click listener for button
    var elButton = event.target; // The button that you clicked
    var elLi = elButton.parentNode; // The <li> element that button was in
    list.removeChild(elLi); // Remove the <li> element from the list
  }.bind(this)); // Bind the this so the "event" parameter will be the clicked button
  
  var newItem = document.createElement("li"); // Create a new <li> element
  newItem.appendChild(newButton); // Add the button to that element
  list.appendChild(newItem); // Add the <li> element to the list
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
```

Edit: Since you want several listitems to be removed when the button is clicked you can very simply extrapolate by adding another layer of lis. As such:

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list"); // The list element

addButton = document.getElementById("btnAdd"); // The add button
addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newButton = document.createElement("button"); // Create a new button
  var btnText = document.createTextNode("Remove"); // Create the button's text
  newButton.appendChild(btnText); // Add the text to the button
  
  newButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) { // Create click listener for button
    var elButton = event.target; // The button that you clicked
    var elLi = elButton.parentNode; // The <li> element that button was in
    var parentLi = elLi.parentNode; // The <li> element all the other <li>s are in
    list.removeChild(parentLi); // Remove the <li> element from the list
  }.bind(this)); // Bind the this so the "event" parameter will be the clicked button
  
  var newItemBtn = document.createElement("li"); // Create a new <li> element
  newItemBtn.appendChild(newButton); // Add the button to that element
  
  // Create other child <li>s
  var newItem1 = document.createElement("li");
  newItem1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item 1"));
  var newItem2 = document.createElement("li");
  newItem2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item 2"));
  var newItem3 = document.createElement("li");
  newItem3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item 3"));
  
  var parentLi = document.createElement("li"); // Create a new <li> parent element to wrap the other <li> elements in
  parentLi.appendChild(newItem1); // Add the child <li> to that element
  parentLi.appendChild(newItem2); // Add the child <li> to that element
  parentLi.appendChild(newItem3); // Add the child <li> to that element
  parentLi.appendChild(newItemBtn); // Add the child <li> to that element
  list.appendChild(parentLi); // Add the <li> element to the list
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Some listitem</li>
</ul>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. I need to remove a list item that has several list items in it. That code only gets rid of the button. <li id="parentlistitem"><li/><li/><button>Remove</button></li>

Comment: And you can't extrapolate that from this answer? Just add another level of lis then and go up one more parentNode.... The point of stackoverflow is to give coders tools to solve their problems, to nudge them in the direction. Not to simply write their code. I have edited the code, as I am thinking you mean the problem should be.  But honestly, we could write it a 100 different ways to get it "just right".